# h.264 training of parsing

Tags: java, c++, c, h.264

I'm trying to understand process of parsing h.264 NAL units (to extract information about slices, macroblocks etc.), so I'm writing simple bit stream parser for h.264
Are there any example (training) files, which, for example, contains single NAL unit or single slice?
Does anybody knows where I can get such training data?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want training data, you can download the H.264 reference software from http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/. Note that this reference software is written in c++ though. You don't need to be well versed in c++ though, you do need to be able to build the encoder and then you can use it as a tool to generate .264 data.

The bin directory contains .yuv files (raw uncompressed) and using the configuration files you can then generate .264 files. If you want a single NAL Unit as you specified, you can configure the encoder via the configuration file to only encode a single video frame using the *FramesToBeEncoded* parameter. If you open the generated .264 using a hex editor you can identify the NAL units by their start codes. By adapting the configuration files, you should be able to generate your desired test data.

Note that even if you only generate one frame, there might be more than one NAL unit inside the .264 file since the sequence and picture parameter sets are prepended to the IDR frame. You could easily isolate and separate e.g in c++ by searching for the start codes.